# Search for number in array, Android

Tags: android, arrays, search, numbers

I'm searching for numbers in my app, but it does not work, where is the problem please ?!
numrat is int[]  and fint is a number from fytyratint[]...

```
        int fint = fytyratint[nrRendor];
        int nse = Arrays.binarySearch(numrat, fint);


            if (nse <0 ){
                pS++;
                tvS.setText("Sakt: "+ Integer.toString(pS));
            }
            else
            {
                pG++;
                tvG.setText("Gabimet: " + Integer.toString(pG));
            }
```

So nse must be negative if number does not exist in int[] numrat and must be positive if fint exists on int[] numrat..
This is what I read on internet..
but in my example it is always negative.. ??!!

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `Arrays.binarySearch()` to work you should **sort your array** like written [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20byte)):

> binarySearch() ...
>   Performs a binary search for value in the **ascending sorted array**
>   array. **Searching in an unsorted array has an undefined result**. It's
>   also undefined which element is found if there are multiple
>   occurrences of the same element.

You may do it like this:

```
Arrays.sort(numrat);
Arrays.binarySearch(numrat, fint);
```